# Is it good practice to define scope of dependencies in Maven BOM (bill of materials)?

Tags: maven, maven-bom

I have a `pom.xml` like this to be used as a BOM (Bill of Materials). One of the defined dependencies is a `*-test` artifact used for testing your code that uses the libraries from this BOM.

The question is: is it appropriate / good practice to specify that the `*-test` artifact is just for `test` scope in the BOM itself, or should this be left for the users of the BOM to specify in their project's POM, if needed?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.mylib</groupId>
    <artifactId>mylib-bom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>MyLib (Bill of Materials)</name>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example.mylib</groupId>
                <artifactId>mylib-cool-library</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example.mylib</groupId>
                <artifactId>mylib-test</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope> <!-- === HERE === -->
            </dependency>    
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>    
</project>
```

I was looking at how existing projects do this and, for example, the Spring Framework BOM does not, indeed, define any scope explicitly. But I am still wondering if there is some unwritten rule for this or something like that?

Comment: It is best practice to let the user of your pom decide which scope the appripriate dependency should have...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best practice is to let the user decide scope, and *not* set it in BOM (or parent pom).

When you set scope in BOM (to anything other than `compile`) you change the default scope for that dependency, as seen from user projects. The default dependency scope in maven is `compile`, so it's common practice to omit scope for a dependency when you want it to be compile. If the BOM imposes another scope, it can be a nasty surprise for other developers that use the BOM (or even yourself at a later point in time).

Comment: So essentially, the scope in the BOM doesn't follow the documented behaviour - <scope>compile</scope> and no scope behave differently, when they occur in a BOM. This is something I wish the Maven docs themselves were more clear on.

Comment: @Trejkaz Since `compile` is the default scope, you can set that in BOM without changing behaviour for dependent projects, although it's redundant. My answer was focused around setting e.g. `test` or `provided` in BOM. I edited my answer to clarify.