# Why isn't Maven overridden scope recognized transitively?

Tags: java, maven

This is an interesting state of affairs in Maven that I didn't expect. Maybe someone can explain exactly why this is happening.

I have a parent POM `foobar-parent` that declares `logback-classic` with a `test` scope in the `<dependencyManagement>` section.

I have a separate project project `example` that has its own `example-parent`, which inherits from `foobar-parent` and also serves as a parent to its submodules.

One submodule `example-foo` overrides the dependency `logback-classic` and gives it `compile` scope:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Lastly I have another submodule `example-bar` which uses `example-foo` as a dependency.

Strangely, for the effective POM of `example-bar`, it shows that `logback-classic` has `test` scope!! Since `example-foo` declares `logback-classic` to be of `compile` scope (meaning it is required at compile time), and since `example-bar` has a compile-time dependency to `example-foo`, I expected `example-bar` to bring in `logback-classic` as a transitive dependency.

The way I interpret this is that the `test` scope specified in the `<dependencyManagement>` management section of a parent POM will override the scope of a transitive dependency from the `compile` scope!! Is this a correct interpretation, and is that how Maven is supposed to work?

Comment: Just make those dependency as `dependencyManagement` in `foo` parent pom insteed of `dependencies`

Comment: IMO, best practice is to use `dependencyManagement` only for version, not for scope. That way, you avoid unpleasant surprises. A transitive dependency will be pulled in with the correct scope, and if you omit scope for a direct dependency it will have compile scope as expected. See also this related SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47394837/is-it-good-practice-to-define-scope-of-dependencies-in-maven-bom-bill-of-materi/47402262#47402262

Comment: Sometimes scope sohuld be included - eg for Lombok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: "dependency management takes precedence over dependency mediation for transitive dependencies" (taken from [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html))

Comment: Thanks for the reference! This may have even been something I had read earlier but it's not exactly intuitive so maybe I forgot. I'm not saying it's nonintuitive, but… at least unexpected. Cheers!